# How to remove index.php from www to non-www .htaccess redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

When I go to

```
www.example.co/courses
```

I get redirected to

```
https://example.co/index.php/courses
```

I want to get redirected to

```
https://example.co/courses
```

**What I have tried**

Here is my `.htaccess` file at the moment:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

How do I remove the `/index.php/` part of the redirected URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your external redirects in the wrong place. They need to go *before* your internal rewrites (before your *front controller*). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.twocan\.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://twocan.co/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you have your external redirects after the internal rewrite then the request gets rewritten to `/index.php/...` which then gets turned into an external redirect (the rewrite process loops in `.htaccess`, so it only gets rewritten to `index.php` on the first loop).

Comment: Wow, that does make perfect sense. Thank you for teaching me something new!